# What are the parameters for washing after excusing one's self in the middle of the meal?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, bathroom, food

If I recall correctly from Chayei Adam and elsewhere, if you're in the middle of a bread-based meal and excuse yourself to defecate, *first of all you should wash with soap and water for hygienic purposes, as you always should after using the restroom! But after that,*   you do a ritual washing and make "al netilas yadayim" as you usually would when starting to eat bread.

[This halacha is the subject of some discussion, and not agreed-upon by everyone.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/new-al-netilas-yadayim-after-washing-after-defecating-during-meal)

*According to those who do require washing,* however, what are the parameters of this washing?  Can I talk afterwards?  Do I say a new hamotzee if I'm having more bread?  What if I wasn't in the mood for more bread, just cake?  Just meat?  Just water?

Comment: Great question, but I would not be quick to assume that one should make a new "al netilas yadayim". Although MB says in BH that one should ( http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=106 ) and Aruch Hashulhan says that no one would say that you should not say the bracha if you defecated ( http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=300 ) continued

Comment: he must have missed the Taz ( http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=227 ) who brings a proof from the Rema ( http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=150 ) that the opinion of the Maharshal to not make a new netilas yadayim within one seudah would apply to leaving to defecate as well. Because of the Taz's reasoning, SA HaRav holds ( http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24691&st=&pgnum=465 ) one should not make the bracha based on the principle "safek brachos lehakel.

Comment: Rabbi Welcher described it as: "it's the subject of a great deal of discussion in the Achronim, but it appears the conclusion is to make a bracha."  My question is according to those opinions.  Thanks for quoting the others.

Comment: an important parameter is to use soap and water. this even if doing a halachic hand-washing after.

Comment: Josh, thanks! Duly noted, I'm adding that!

Comment: If anyone would like to produce a halakhic source for not talking after נטילת ידיים, (i.e. showing it is actually halakha and not a minhag) I would certainly like to see it.

Comment: אהרון מיכאל נחמן, Welcome to judaism.SE! I think this comment could be rephrased into an excellent [question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rabbi Yosef Gavriel Bechhofer, if you want to eat more bread, you should wash, say *al netilat yadayim* and then not talk until you say *hamotzee.*

If you don't want to eat more bread, you don't have to wash.

Comment: Why do you need a new Hamotzi?

Comment: Not sure; hence my question originally what exactly the parameters here are. Rabbi Bechhofer said new hamotzi.

Comment: Shalom, your take on Rabbi Bechofer is against the Rema O.C. 178:7 here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=589.  If there is a alternate opinion, please quote the source.

Comment: @YDK: as Rabbi Welcher said: "it's a subject of much debate in the Achronim", so don't ask me from a Ramah. See Yahu's linked question (and answer) above for other opinions. This isn't "my take on Rabbi Bechhofer", it's what I heard directly from him. Again, that's one opinion, there are certainly others!

Comment: Shalom, I was talking about hamotzi.

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know, whether you make a bracha after going to the bathroom could be a mi.yodeya question in its own right.

The basis for not talking after netilas yadayim is "teikef l'netilah seudah".  Since you are already involved in the seudah, there is no issue.  (The eating of bread merely signifies the beginning of the seudah.)

Your bracha rishona on the bread is not affected by going to the bathroom per se.  The only thing that will affect your bracha rishona on bread is hesech daas (see S.A. O.C. 178-179) which is not an issue when just going to the bathroom.

The takanah for netilas yadayim is only for bread.  A similar halacha would be if someone made a mezonos on a doughnut and, after finishing, decided to have another.  Although he may have to bench afterward on what he already ate, he would not recite hamotzi unless he was now going to have an appropriate shiur.

Comment: See my comment on Sholom's question!

Comment: Now see http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2852/new-al-netilas-yadayim-after-washing-after-defecating-during-meal

Answer (score -2):

As for not talking after any נטילת ידיים, there seems to be a misconception among a vast majority of Jews, who hold such a personal custom (as it originated and was intended) as if it is halakha. Surely, nowhere says this custom is halakha, and one certainly can talk after until eating bread.

Comment: Aharon, you should do more research.  The halacha of tekef l'netilas yadayim seudah which is brough in the gemara, is interpreted by Tosfos and Rabeinu Yonah and is also infered by the Yerushalmi.  If your family follows the line of Rambam and Rif, more power to ya'.

Comment: I'd like to see where it says that and what it says, because I have heard from multiple reliable sources that there is no clear Talmudic source for not speaking between nettilath yodhoim and hamossi. Between mayim ahharonim and birkath hammozon is a different story.
And this is why such a halakha does not exist in Mishne Tora, which is a complete halakhic code (unlike, say, Shulhhan `Arukh).

Such an idea of not talking between n"y and hamossi is merely a personal minhagh of the Rosh.

Comment: Well, here is a Talmudic source from a tosefta: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=52b&format=pdf. The sugya starts on the previous page.  Note that Tosfos hold that this is a 4th concept of "immediacy" and does not apply it as an interpretation of tekef lintila bracha found here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=42&format=pdf, whereas others use this gemara to interpret the word "bracha" in the latter citing as bircas hamotzi.

Comment: Obviously, the Rambam had a different answer to why "Tekef lintilah seudah" was left out- we dont pasken like the "davar acher" in the quoted tosefta, but like the first answer.  This needs more explanation of the gemara which is beyond the scope of this comment.