# Are there any sources that say to wash hands with soap after the bathroom?

Tags: sources-mekorot, bathroom, cleaning, personal-hygiene

Are there any sources in Rabbinic literature that mention washing hands with soap after using the bathroom?
I.e that just using the cup (נטילת ידים) isn't sufficient.

An explicit statement would be best, but even something else that talks about washing for cleanliness would be good.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/what-are-the-parameters-for-washing-after-excusing-ones-self-in-the-middle-of-t

Comment: @GershonGold A post by a user with over 80k rep is not automatically Rabbinic literature. ;)

Comment: Correct. And that is why it was placed as a comment.

Comment: Why would you think soap would be required?

Comment: @DoubleAA For cleanliness reasons. I'm hoping some rabbi mentions it.

Comment: ונשמרתם מאד לנפשותיכם?

Comment: This gemara in nedarim 49b is mashma no soap. רבי יוסי ורבי יהודה חד אכיל דייסא באצבעתיה וחד אכיל בהוצא א''ל דאכיל בהוצא לדאכיל באצבעתיה עד מתי אתה מאכילני צואתך אמר ליה דאכיל באצבעתיה לדאכיל בהוצא עד מתי אתה מאכילני רוקך.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59461/5275 **may** be a dupe if you are not restricting your question to just after the bathroom.

Comment: If you use Ivory liquid, you can fulfill the rare mitzva of kiluach ha-shen.